# Django: Programmitically use 'inspectdb' during runtime on dynamic database connections

Tags: python, django, database

I have a Django project where groups of users each have their own database ("projects"). For each project there is an entry, which is saved in a main database. From the main database Django reads all the current projects and makes connections to their database. This is why the connections are not written in settings.py. The piece of code that dynamically connects to the project-databases is run in the root urls.py, since I learned form another thread on stackoverflow that the code there is run once on start-up. Whenever a new project is created by a user, a piece of code creates a new database and connects to the new database by appending a connection to settings.DATABASES (see sample code below).
A external program is triggered to fill the new database with data.

Now the problem is that I cannot immediately use the database, since first I would need to run inspectdb to get the ORM structure for Django.
I want to do this at runtime, because having to shut down the server and restart it would mean other users could not use their projects during that time. But even manually using the commandline, Django answers with an error that the connection does not exist. (I guess it tries to find the connection in the settings.py?). However for projects that I already created an ORM structure the connection is found. So I figure the problem does not lie in the piece of code that appends the connections to settings.DATABASES.

I tried solving the above mentioned problem using

```py
command = 'python manage.py inspectdb --database ' + name + ' > api_manager/schemas/' + name + '.py'
    os.system(command)
```

However, as mentioned above it raises an exception that the connection does not exist.

In settings.py only the default database is present:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': engine,
        'NAME': name,
        'USER': user,
        'PASSWORD': pwd,
        'HOST': host,
        'PORT': port
    }
}
```

In the root urls.py:

```py
...
from myproject.utils import connect_to_db

urlpatterns = [
...
]


# one time execution
for project in Project.objects.all():
    connect_to_db(project.slug)
```

The connect_to_db() code:

```py
def connect_to_db(project):
    settings.DATABASES[project] = {
        'ENGINE': settings.engine,
        'NAME': project,
        'USER': settings.user,
        'PASSWORD': settings.pwd,
        'HOST': settings.host,
        'PORT': settings.port
    }
    print("CONNECTED TO DATABASE: " + project)
```

The project creation:

```py
def create_new_project(project_name):

    slug = slugify(project_name).replace('-', '')
    project_dir = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "projects", slug)

    try:
        # Create entry in default database
        project = Project()
        project.name = project_name
        project.slug = slug
        project.save()
        # Create new database
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE " + slug)

        # Create projects folder in media
        if not os.path.exists(project_dir):
            os.mkdir(project_dir)
            # create some other folders
        else:
            raise Exception("Project folder already exists!")
        connect_to_db(slug)
        return project
    except:
        raise
```

Piece of code that is run after the external program has run:

```py
command = 'python manage.py inspectdb --database ' + name + ' > myapp/schemas/' + name + '.py'
    os.system(command) # raises exception connection 'name' doesn't exist
```

I expect Django to create a new ORM (models.py) file at runtime so my users can immediately use the newly generated database.

EDIT: I tried the same thing with subprocess.run(...) instead of os.system and still no success.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code by rest call:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
# base dir from your's project settings
from project_name.settings import BASE_DIR
import os 

with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'inspected.py'), 'w+') as f
    call_command("inspectdb", stdout=f)
```

...and receive result file near manage.py.